# Insert trigger in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

I am trying to write a trigger that inserts in a log table the date, name of the table I inserted in, the name of the operation (insert, delete, update) and the number of insertion.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Inser]
ON [dbo].[Avion] 
AFTER INSERT
AS  
BEGIN
    DECLARE @codAv int
    DECLARE @NumeAv varchar(100)
    DECLARE @MotorAv varchar(100)

    SELECT @codAv = INSERTED.codA FROM INSERTED
    SELECT @NumeAv = INSERTED.NumeA FROM INSERTED   
    SELECT @MotorAv = INSERTED.Motor FROM INSERTED  

    SELECT @@ROWCOUNT AS INSERTED; 

    INSERT INTO LogM (DataM, Numele, Tipul, Numar) 
    VALUES(GETDATE(), 'Avion', 'Inserare', @@ROWCOUNT);

    PRINT 'INSERT trigger fired.'
END
```

I have a stored procedure where I have something like 20 insertion of this type:

```
INSERT INTO Avion (Motor,NumeA)
VALUES ('Junkers','Focke-Wulf');
```

all separated from one another. When I run that code, the table LogM will be populated with 20 new rows of this type:

```
5 Nov 27 2016 8:58PM  Avion  Inserare  1.00
```

I want to make my trigger to count all the insertion stored in a procedure, then insert in `LogM` only one entry, with the `ROWCOUNT` not being `1.00`, but the number of insertion I made in that stored procedure, and I don't have any idea how can I do this.

Thank you.

Comment: And how sql server should know that it's time to insert data into logm table? I'd suggest to chsnge the logic in your proc and insert all rows with one statement

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` statement that causes this trigger to fire inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `SELECT @codAv = INSERTED.codA FROM INSERTED` - it's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing @@ROWCOUNT you can not just pass the ID?

@@ROWCOUNT works to return the number of rows affected, as you enter one at a time, it will always be one.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Inser]
    ON [dbo].[Avion] 
    AFTER INSERT
    AS  
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @codAv int
    DECLARE @NumeAv varchar(100)
    DECLARE @MotorAv varchar(100)

    SELECT @codAv=INSERTED.codA FROM INSERTED
    SELECT @NumeAv=INSERTED.NumeA FROM INSERTED 
    SELECT @MotorAv=INSERTED.Motor FROM INSERTED    

    INSERT INTO LogM
           (DataM,Numele,Tipul,Numar) 
    VALUES(GETDATE(),'Avion','Inserare',@codAv);
    PRINT 'INSERT trigger fired.'
END
```